# How to create a ModalPopup with a form

Tags: javascript, web, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to create a popup menu which when clicked opens a form to accept user details.Is there a way to create a popup which has a form using Google Closure??

Comment: did you check this link -http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/dialog.html

Comment: I have already gone through it but failed to render a form inside a dialog.

Comment: so you mean in goog.ui.dialog can not render basic html input elements  ?

Comment: here is a very basic popup with input elements - http://jsbin.com/AXosazI/1/

Comment: I want the form elements also to be rendered using google closure. i.e using goog.ui.LabelInput inside the dialog.

Comment: will this work ?  http://jsbin.com/AXosazI/2/

Comment: Both work fine and i actually figured out how to render using google closure by exploring on what you told. But i still have a small issue where the when the popup is invoked for the 1st time the form fields are rendered once for the second time its rendered twice and so on!

Comment: if possible post your code in jsbin

Comment: here is the link. try clicking the button multiple times without reloading.  http://jsbin.com/EciYACu/4

Comment: i think the problem is you are creating popup everytime on click. `Create Once- Show/Hide multiple times` http://jsbin.com/axEqoMa/1/